# Alttool Manual Notarisation of App - The operation couldn’t be completed. Is a directory Is a directory (21)

Tags: xcode, macos, xcrun

I'm having issues with notarizing the app directly in Xcode.Even though i have acceped all agreements and updated the required banking info,the upload step get stuck at authenticating with Apple Service.So i'm trying to use alttool to notarize my app.

- Generated App specific password
- Using the following command

But i keep getting the error

```
my-MacBook-Pro:1.3 my$ xcrun altool --notarize-app --primary-bundle-id "me.myapp" --username me@live.com --password mypass  --file "myapp.app"
*** Error: Notarization failed for 'myapp.app'.
*** Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Is a directory Is a directory (21)
 {
    "_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey" = 21;
    "_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey" = 1;
}
```

I'm running Xcode 13.1 on macOS Monterey 12.0.1

Answer (score 0):

if it's still actual , you need to zip your binary first and then try to notarize it

```
xcrun altool --notarize-app --primary-bundle-id "your.app.id.here" --username="your_account" --password "keychain_or_password" --file your_binary.zip
```

don't forget to update with real values